# .SECONDARY giving undesired effect in Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a make file that looks something like the following...

```
.SECONDARY: 

THRESHOLDS=010 020 030 040 050

FIRST=$(foreach T,$(THRESHOLDS),test.$(T).txt)

$(FIRST) :
    echo $@ > $@

composite.txt : $(FIRST)
    cat $^ > $@
```

The main difference between my example above and reality is that the rule to build the `test.*.txt` files has prerequisites. For this example, when I do `make composite.txt`, it builds `test.010.txt`, `test.020.txt`, etc.

```
$ make composite.txt 
echo test.010.txt > test.010.txt
echo test.020.txt > test.020.txt
echo test.030.txt > test.030.txt
echo test.040.txt > test.040.txt
echo test.050.txt > test.050.txt
cat test.010.txt test.020.txt test.030.txt test.040.txt test.050.txt > composite.txt
```

If I add values to `THRESHOLDS`...

```
.SECONDARY: 

THRESHOLDS=010 020 030 040 050 015 025 035 045

FIRST=$(foreach T,$(THRESHOLDS),test.$(T).txt)

$(FIRST) :
    echo $@ > $@

composite.txt : $(FIRST)
    cat $^ > $@
```

I get...

```
$ make composite.txt 
make: `composite.txt' is up to date.
```

If I remove the `.SECONDARY:` line, it builds the new `test.*.txt` and `composite.txt` files. I have the `.SECONDARY:` rule because I don't want `make` to delete the intermediate files. I would also like to treat all of the intermediate files (e.g. `test.*.txt`) as secondary files so that they aren't deleted. Reading through [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html#Chained-Rules), I see that it says, "When a file is secondary, make **will not create the file merely because it does not already exist**, but make does not automatically delete the file". My question is how do I have make create the file if it doesn't exist and not delete it when it is created?

Comment: There are no intermediate files in your makefile, so nothing will be deleted.  Just remove `.SECONDARY` and it will work as you expect.

Comment: In the real example that this is simulating, there are intermediate files that I would like to preserve.

Comment: It would be good if your example was close enough to the actual code to show the problem you're seeing.  Typically I recommend that people just declare some target somewhere in their makefile that lists the files to be preserved as prerequisites.  It doesn't have to be a target you actually use: any mention of the files as either explicit targets or prerequisites is sufficient to make them non-intermediate.

Comment: Thanks. I think that should do it